# Man "spricht mit Akzent" - aber mit was "schreibt" man?

Tags: accent

Oft hört man dem gesprochenen Deutsch eines Menschen dessen Herkunft an, wenn es sich nicht um die Muttersprache handelt, und sagt "er spricht mit Akzent".

Sehr viel ungenauer ist es, die Muttersprache dem *geschriebenen* Wort zu entnehmen (hat man öfter mit solcher Art der Kommunikation zu tun, kann sich ein gewisses Gefühl entwickeln - ich habe das bei Deutsch schreibenden Franzosen).

Nun suche ich einen Ausdruck dafür, also quasi: "Sie schreibt mit Akzent".

Gibt es einen?

Comment: Wie wäre es mit Sprachmixen wie: Denglish (Deutsch mit englischen Einfluss), Kanak Sprak (Deutsch mit Türkischem Einfluss), Japanglish (Japanisch mit englischen Einfluss)?

Comment: @Iris Kanak Sprak empfinde ich als abwertend, gibt's etwa keinen neutralen Begriff? (Türkendeutsch?)

Comment: @c.p. In Berlin kenn ich das auch als Kiezdeutsch. Die Soziolinguistin Diana Marossek spricht von [Kurzdeutsch](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kurzdeutsch). Kurzdeutsch ist aber eigentlich ein neuer Sprachdialekt, der auch von Nicht-Türken gesprochen wird.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ich würde vermutlich versuchen, das zu umschreiben, vor dem Hintergrund, dass es sich ja bei Beidem um zwei Seiten der selben Medaille handelt:

> "Sie verwendet Deutsch mit leichtem französischen Einschlag"
>
> "Man merkt ihr den französischen Akzent auch im Schriftverkehr an"

"Sie schreibt mit Akzent" ist mir zu wenig. Es klingt unvollständig und vielleicht sogar mißverständlich (möglicherweise, weil in der Schriftsprache der Akzent etwas anderes bedeutet?).

Comment: Ich hätte auch sofort Einschlag verwendet. Ich glaube, dass das Problem darin besteht, dass geschriebene Sprache mehr standadisiert ist, und daher ein Akzent eher als einfach falsch gilt.

Answer (score 6):

Wenn der Eindruck vom Satzbau herrührt kann man sagen: "Er schreibt mit Dänischem Satzbau".

Oder jemand verwendet Redewedungen, die im Englischen typisch sind - tut er nicht? Dann könnte man das konkret so sagen.

Oder die Schreib Weise wäre in einer anderen Sprache korrekt.

Freilich könnte man unbewußt an eine Sprache erinnert werden, ohne sich bewußt zu sein, woher der Eindruck rührt. Auch dann könnte man es einfach sagen. Es ist ganz einfach: Man sagt, was man sagen will. "Ich entnehme Deiner Schreibweise, dass Du Österreicher bist! :)" (berl.: 'Deiner Schreibe').

So wie er schreiben viele Schweizer.

Answer (score 3):

Der Begriff "Akzent" bezieht sich meines Erachtens spezifisch auf die spezielle Aussprache von Lauten und Betonung von Wörtern, und dezidiert *nicht* auf Fragen des Satzbaus, der Wortwahl oder der Grammatik. Insbesondere kann man perfektes Deutsch mit deutlichem Akzent sprechen (oder auch deutsche Texte fehlerfrei, aber mit Akzent vortragen), sowie umgekehrt akzentlos fehlerhaftes Deutsch sprechen.

Die Analogie für Schriftstücke wäre, wenn man aus dem *Schriftbild* die Nationalität erkennen oder erraten kann. Falls das möglich ist (keine Ahnung ob das geht, ich habe mit fremdsprachigen Handschriften keine Erfahrung), würde ich das dann auch entsprechend ausdrücken, etwa:

> Sie hat eine sehr französische Schrift.

Gemeint ist hier aber vermutlich etwas anderes, nämlich, dass in der Sprache Konstruktionen auftauchen, die typisch für französischsprachige Personen sind (was beim Sprechen durchaus mit einem französischen Akzent kombiniert sein kann, aber nicht muss). In diesem Fall finde ich [die erste Version von Mac](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/2666/1684) gut:

> Sie verwendet Deutsch mit leichtem französischen Einschlag.

Hingegen wäre meines Erachtens sein zweiter Vorschlag, "Man merkt ihr den französischen Akzent auch im Schriftverkehr an" allenfalls dann angebracht, wenn sich die Eigenheiten der Aussprache auch in der Schreibweise wiederfinden (beispielsweise wenn jemand, der bestimmte "e"s immer wie "ä"s ausspricht, an den entsprechenden Stellen auch "ä" statt "e" schreibt).

Comment: Sehr schöne Elaboration. +1 auch für die Unterscheidung zwischen Akzent und Fehlerhaftigkeit, die unabhängig voneinander sind.

Answer (score 1):

Ich kenne keinen passenden Ausdruck bezogen auf Schrift. Es gibt aber zwei andere Ausdrücke die bezogen auf Schrift meiner Meinung nach besser aussehen:

- holpriges Deutsch
- gebrochenes Deutsch

Sowohl *Sie schreibt holpriges Deutsch* wie auch *Sie schreibt gebrochenes Deutsch* funktionieren in meinen Augen besser als *Sie schreibt mit Akzent*.

Comment: Ich wäre damit sehr vorsichtig - m.E. sind beide Versionen sehr viel stärker als das ursprüngliche Beispiel. Ein Akzent allein bedeutet noch nicht, dass die Sprache *schlecht* gesprochen wird - "holprig" und "gebrochen" sagen aber genau das aus.

Comment: Eine gelegentliche fremdssprachige Metapher ist noch nicht holprig oder gebrochen.

Comment: @Phira Ein _Akzent_ und eine _gelegentliche fremdsprachige Metapher_ haben eigentlich nichts miteinander zu tun ...

Comment: @Mac Das empfinde ich nicht so, aber vielleicht liegt's an mir ...

Comment: @takrl : Was stellst du dir denn unter einem *schriftlichen* Akzent vor? Ein mündlicher Akzent hat jedenfalls nicht automatisch die Konnotation holprig und gebrochen, daher ist meine Interpretation der Frage, dass man am geschriebenen Deutsch die Herkunft ablesen kann. Das kann zum Beispiel auch daran liegen, dass man Konstruktionen und Metaphern bevorzugt, die im Deutschen zwar korrekt sind, aber nur selten verwendet werden. Natürlich kann es auch daran liegen, dass man holprige und gebrochene ungrammatische Sätze spricht, aber das muss eben nicht sein.

Comment: Um das noch konkreter zu machen: Auch wenn ich einen korrekten französischen Satz mit richtiger Aussprache auf die Reihe kriege, kann ein Gesprächspartner leicht meinen Akzent erkennen, wenn ich als Füllwort "äh" statt "öh"(=euh) verwende. Das würde wohl kaum jemand als gebrochenes Französisch bezeichnen, aber als Spionin wäre ich schon entlarvt.